# How to load file from folder within a gradle external library (JAVA)

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

This is probably something simple. But how can you load a file that is within a specific folder in an external library that is loaded using gradle/maven? Say you want to load [DTLZ1.2D.PF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoo0t.png) as shown in the image at the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the following command

```
 compile fileTree('libfold/*.jar')
```

=================================

This is the way to read files within jar.

Example(junit-4.12.jar!LICENSE-junit.txt)：

```
public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.net.URL url = junit.textui.TestRunner.class.getResource("/LICENSE-junit.txt");
        // print: jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar!/LICENSE-junit.txt
        System.out.println(url);
        try {
            java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(url.openStream()).useDelimiter("\n");
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.next());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to call the file in a class I am using

Comment: @Korogba Of course, you can get the file via the ClassLoader.getResource() method. This has nothing to do with gradle/maven.

Comment: sorry for the troubles, can you show an example of ` ClassLoader.getResource()` to get the file from the image in the question?

Comment: @Korogba I added. Please look at the contents of the above.

Comment: Thanks! You use a class within the library to load the resource.